# Setting a String Variable in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis, set

I am trying to set a string variable in SSIS using an execute sql command.

[image]

For this task I have implemented this expression:

```
"select" +@[User::ID]+ "=  columnA
from table
where columnB = '123' "
```

Just to check that  I am doing this in the right way I have added and script task to show, using a message box ,the value of the variable

But when I execute the task I am getting this error message from the execute sql task:

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query ""select" +@[User::ID]+ "=  >columnA  from table  where columnB = '123' "
>   ..." failed with the following error:
>   "Incorrect syntax near '='.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with
>   the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set
>   correctly, or connection not established correctly.

I have also tried to follow this example, but always with an error as an answer
http://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2012/08/how-to-set-and-use-variables-in-ssis-execute-sql-task/

Answer (score 3):

This is not how you do it. You need to setup your Execute SQL Task, so that it has a result set of a single row and type your SQL query as if you type it in management studio. See this snapshot

[image]

Then you will go to the result set of the task, and tell it to assign the results to your variable. See this snapshot

[image]

You need to make sure that your query will only return a single row. Otherwise, you will get an error.

Comment: You are welcome @d2907. Can you please mark this as an accepted answer if it answers your question.